# List through fieldName: illegal value

Tags: nodes, entities

[image]

I have created content type with field as List(text).
If I select any of above option and try to save it, it through "fieldName: illegal value" error.But if I modified option in below format and then try to save it. It get saved successfully.

```
-option1

-option2

-option3

-option4
```

Does list doesnot support first format? Is there any other way to resolve this without changing its format ?

Comment: Hi thanks for response. Yups its option group. Also attached image related to it.

Comment: here the problem is you havent provided the key properly . So its not able to store the value or get the value

Comment: Hi Shreya, so how should I provide key without changing format specified in image. Can you please help by giving any example.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using [`hook_form_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x) function.

I've tested the following code on my instance. It's working fine.

Use the following code in your custom module.

```
function YOUR_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {     
        if ($form['#form_id'] == 'YOUR-CONTENT-TYPE_node_form') {
         $form['YOUR-FILED-NAME']['und']['#options'] = array (
       'Group1' => array(
          1 => 'Option1',
          2 => 'Option2',

        ),
        'Group2' => array(
          3 => 'Option3',
          4 => 'Option4',
        ),
    );
    return $form;
        }
    }
```